# Eliminating Predictor Variables and Comparing Classification methods to find the best model

Tags: r, classification, logistic-regression, roc

I am currently working with a dataset with a binary response variable with 2 levels. I have approx 32 predictor variables - some factors and some numeric. I used glm and based on the p values removed some of the predictor variables that I thought were insignificant. However, when I run the deviance test I always get zero and my ROC curve is upside down - this can be corrected by putting the TPR on the x axis but I think this is incorrect.

Can anyone provide any suggestions on what I could potentially be doing wrong?
Thanks a million!

The code below represents the categories I think are significant. They are all categorical.

```
data_analysis <- glm(PainDiagnosis~PainLocation+Criterion2+Criterion6+Criterion8+
Criterion9+Criterion13, data=dat, family="binomial") summary(data_analysis) coef(data_analysis) anova(data_analysis, test="Chisq")
```

```
resDev_glm <- residuals(fit_glm, type = "deviance")
testDev_glm <- sum(resDev_glm^2)
modMat_glm <- model.matrix(fit_glm) # model matrix
NO_glm <- nrow(unique(modMat_glm)) # number of unique observations
m_glm <- length(fit_glm$coefficients) # number of parameters
nrow(dat)
NO_glm
testDev_glm
1 - pchisq(testDev_glm, NO_glm-m_glm)
```

```
library(ROCR)
predObj <- prediction(fitted(fit_glm), dat$PainDiagnosis)
perf <- performance(predObj, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf)
abline(0,1, col = "darkorange2", lty = 2) # add bisect line
```

2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), 
    DurationCurrent = structure(c(5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
    4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 
    2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
    6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
    2L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
    6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
    6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
    3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
    4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0-3 weeks", 
    "4-6 weeks", "7-12 weeks", "4-6 months", "7-12 months", "> 1 year"

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your work. Otherwise, if this is a theoretical issue, you could post it to Cross Validated which is a better outlet for this type of question.

Comment: So the code I have is as follows:
data_analysis <- glm(PainDiagnosis~PainLocation+Criterion2+Criterion6+Criterion8+Criterion9+Criterion13, data=dat,
           family="binomial")
summary(data_analysis)
coef(data_analysis)
anova(data_analysis, test="Chisq")

Comment: @Soph91 please edit your question and include the code there directly

Comment: Updated now - sorry I haven't used this too often!

Comment: @Soph91 a sample dataset may be needed in order to replicate your results. Please edit your question with the output of the function `dput` used on your dataset `dat`

Comment: @RicS I was trying to recreate something similar to this as a starting point https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/270798_46c7a5a8fb7d4980af1b942443271a6f.html - my dataset is similar to the one in this example except I have a number of categorical predictors as well. I've included the dput output - I am not too familiar to this function.